# How to hide/exclude data-frame columns with respect to another table

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I got a requirement to hide few columns with respect to another dataframe/table which contains list of columns that needs to hide.

df

```
+------+----------+-------+---+---+------+----+----+----+
|Gender| Mobilenum|address|age| id|id_row|name|role|unit|
+------+----------+-------+---+---+------+----+----+----+
|     M|  96226126| SDF-03| 24|101|     1| ash| SSE| DNA|
|     M| 961267126| DSR-09| 24|102|     2|sony|  TA| DNA|
|     M|  96226126| DDD-09| 24|103|     3|zoro|  PM| DNA|
|     M|3962267126| DFG-07| 24|104|     4| max|  SM| DNA|
|     M| 902267126| ASC-09| 24|105|     5| ben| VPM| DNA|
+------+----------+-------+---+---+------+----+----+----+
```

df_col

```
+---------+
|   column|
+---------+
|   id_row|
|Mobilenum|
|  address|
|      age|
|   Gender|
+---------+
```

Here i need to hide columns present in df with respect to df_col

expected output

```
+---+----+----+----+
| id|name|role|unit|
+---+----+----+----+
|101| ash| SSE| DNA|
|102|sony|  TA| DNA|
|103|zoro|  PM| DNA|
|104| max|  SM| DNA|
|105| ben| VPM| DNA|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code.

```
c1_L = df_col.rdd.collect()
c1_L1 = [x.column for x in c1_L]
c_L = df.columns
final_df = df.select([x for x in c_L if x not in c1_L1])
final_df.show()
```

output will be

```
+---+----+----+----+
| id|name|role|unit|
+---+----+----+----+
|101| ash| SSE| DNA|
|102|sony|  TA| DNA|
|103|zoro|  PM| DNA|
|104| max|  SM| DNA|
|105| ben| VPM| DNA|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: This works good. can you please brief about c1_L1? what exactly happening

Comment: when u `collect` c1_L it gives you row List `[Row(column='id_row'), Row(column='Mobilenum'), Row(column='address'), Row(column='age'), Row(column='Gender')]` to make it proper list i am calling `x.column` then it gives
`['id_row', 'Mobilenum', 'address', 'age', 'Gender']`